# Can I use no thread synchronization here?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

I am researching mutexes.

I come up with this example that seems to work without any synchronization.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <thread>

#include <iostream>

constexpr size_t COUNT = 10000000;

int g_x = 0;

void p1(){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i){
        ++g_x;
    }
}

void p2(){
    int a = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i){
        if (a > g_x){
            std::cout << "Problem detected" << '\n';
        }

        a = g_x;
    }
}

int main(){
    std::thread t1{ p1 };
    std::thread t2{ p2 };

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::cout << g_x << '\n';
}
```

My assumptions are following:

Thread 1 change the value of `g_x`, but it is the only thread that change the value, so theoretically this suppose to be OK.

Thread 2 reads the value of `g_x`. Reads suppose to be atomic on x86 and ARM. So there must be no problem there too. I have example with several read threads and it works OK too.

With other words, write is not shared and reads are atomic.

Are the assumptions correct?

Comment: let at some time `t1` will be `a > g_x1` (where `g_x1` value of `g_x` at time `t1`). but `a == g_x0` - at some time `t0` (`t0 <= t1`) `a` is assigned from `g_x`. so will be `t0 <= t1` and `g_x0 > g_x1`. but from another side we only increment `g_x` - so `t0 <= t1` => `g_x0 <= g_x1` - contradiction. as result can say `a > g_x` never can happens. but what you try prove here ? for this kind of code (when one thread increment int variable) and another simply read this int at random time - not needed synchronization. but so what ?

Comment: `if (a > g_x){` this is kind of test to show that `g_x` only increasing. Do you suggest any different test?

Comment: test for what ? what you try prove or refute ? however if i not mistake - in your "test" `(a <= g_x)` always - by design. an not related to synchronization here

Comment: Well, I try to proof that there are no 'junk' inside `g_x`

Comment: junk and must not be in your case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's certainly a data race here: `g_x` is not an `std::atomic`; it is written to by one thread, and read from by another. So the results are undefined.

Note that the CPU memory model is only part of the deal. The compiler might do all sorts of optimizations (using registers, reordering etc.) if you don't declare your shared variables properly.

As for mutexes, you do not need one here. Declaring `g_x` as atomic should remove the UB and guarantee proper communication between the threads. Btw, the for in p2 can probably be optimized out even if you're using atomics, but I assume this is just a reduced code and not the real thing.

Comment: Do I need mutex for reading as well? (I know atomic will be best choice)

Comment: If you're not using atomic or fences, then yes. But that's an overkill in your case. Atomics add overhead to memory operations only if the architecture's memory model is too relaxed for you needs. If it isn't, the only cost of atomics is avoiding optimizations - and you definitively want then avoided.

Comment: I changed it to atomic and `g_x.is_lock_free()` is true. How this is related to the situation.

Comment: @Nick - atomic variables work just fine in the context where you're using `g_x`. `is_lock_free` is about the nature of the implementation, and needn't concern you at this point.

Comment: Data race?  The only thing that's going to make the program print out "Problem detected" is if the value that the `p2()` thread reads for `g_x` in the `if` statement is older than the value that it "previously" read and assigned to `a`.  The question here is not about which one of two threads wins a race, it's a question about the order in which the reads performed by a single thread actually occur.

Comment: @jameslarge that `if` statement is of little interest. The code in the question certainly includes a _data race_, which does not imply a competition but lack of ordering, and yielding undefined behavior in C++. Given that race, the order in which reads are performed is, well, undefined. For instance, the compiler can store the value of `g_x` in a register, avoiding further memory accesses. Anyway, the actual algorithm here is less important than the fundamental issue its implementation raises.